# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier. Works in Chrome, but not in Safari or Firefox

Tags: javascript, loops, cross-browser, syntax-error

So I've had a search around, and can't for the life of me understand why this would work perfectly in one browser, and not in the others. On line 13 I'm getting this error in Safari:

[image]

On Firefox, I don't get any errors, but the Script breaks in the same fashion. I've tried making the for loop `for ( var p in productFamily )` or `for ( let p of productFamily )` but it just breaks the script.

Am I looping incorrectly?

Here is my code:

```
$(window).load(function(){

 // All possible families are defined here...
 var productFamily = ["Beaches","Leios","Lull"];

// All possible product types are defined here...
var productType = ["Shelter","Restroom"];

// All possible product sizes are defined here...
var sizeRange = ["4x4","4x8","6x4","6x8","8x4","8x6"];

// Here we loop through each Family, Type and Size...
for ( let p in productFamily ) {
for ( let t in productType ) {
  for ( let i in sizeRange ) {

    // Get all of the select types...
    $('select[name="properties[' + productFamily[p] + ' ' + productType[t] + ' Size]"],'+
      'select[name="properties[' + productFamily[p] + ' ' + productType[t] + ' ' + sizeRange[i] + ' Frame]"],'+
      'select[name="properties[' + productFamily[p] + ' ' + productType[t] + ' ' + sizeRange[i] + ' Fasteners]"],'+
      'select[name="properties[' + productFamily[p] + ' ' + productType[t] + ' ' + sizeRange[i] + ' Roof]"],'+
      'select[name="properties[' + productFamily[p] + ' ' + productType[t] + ' ' + sizeRange[i] + ' Column Infill]"],'+
      'select[name="properties[' + productFamily[p] + ' ' + productType[t] + ' ' + sizeRange[i] + ' Soffit and Sunscreen]"],'+
      'select[name="properties[' + productFamily[p] + ' ' + productType[t] + ' ' + sizeRange[i] + ' Columns]"]').change(function(){

        // Get the values of all the selects as they change...
        var mySizeSelection = $('select[name="properties[' + productFamily[p] + ' ' + productType[t] + ' Size]"]').val();
        var myFrameSelection = $('select[name="properties[' + productFamily[p] + ' ' + productType[t] + ' ' + sizeRange[i] + ' Frame]"]').val();
        var myFastenersSelection = $('select[name="properties[' + productFamily[p] + ' ' + productType[t] + ' ' + sizeRange[i] + ' Fasteners]"]').val();
        var myColumnSelection = $('select[name="properties[' + productFamily[p] + ' ' + productType[t] + ' ' + sizeRange[i] + ' Columns]"]').val();
        var myInfillSelection = $('select[name="properties[' + productFamily[p] + ' ' + productType[t] + ' ' + sizeRange[i] + ' Column Infill]"]').val();
        var myRoofSelection = $('select[name="properties[' + productFamily[p] + ' ' + productType[t] + ' ' + sizeRange[i] + ' Roof]"]').val();
        var mySoffitSelection = $('select[name="properties[' + productFamily[p] + ' ' + productType[t] + ' ' + sizeRange[i] + ' Soffit and Sunscreen]"]').val();
        var empty;

        // This changes the formatting of the size selection...
        if ( mySizeSelection == "4x4" ) {
          mySizeSelection = "44";
        } else if ( mySizeSelection == "4x8" ) {
          mySizeSelection = "48";
        } else if ( mySizeSelection == "6x4" ) {
          mySizeSelection = "64";
        } else if ( mySizeSelection == "6x8" ) {
          mySizeSelection = "68";
        } else if ( mySizeSelection == "8x4" ) {
          mySizeSelection = "84";
        } else {
          mySizeSelection = "86";
        }

        // This changes the formatting of the Frame selection...
        if ( myFrameSelection == "Galvanised" ) {
          myFrameSelection = "G";
        } else if ( myFrameSelection = "Painted" ) {
          myFrameSelection = "P";
        } else {
          myFrameSelection = "G";
        }

        // This changes the formatting of the Column selection...
        if ( myColumnSelection == "Galvanised" ) {
          myColumnSelection = "G";
        } else if ( myColumnSelection = "Painted" ) {
          myColumnSelection = "P";
        } else {
          myColumnSelection = "G";
        }

        // This changes the formatting of the Roof selection...
        if ( productFamily[p] == "Beaches" ) {
          if ( myRoofSelection == "Colorbond" ) {
            myRoofSelection = "C";
          } else if ( myRoofSelection == "Polycarbonite"  ) {
            myRoofSelection = "C";
          } else if ( myRoofSelection == "None" ) {
            myRoofSelection = "C";
          } else {
            myRoofSelection = "C";
          }
        } else {
          if ( myRoofSelection == "Colorbond" ) {
            myRoofSelection = "C";
          } else if ( myRoofSelection == "Polycarbonite"  ) {
            myRoofSelection = "P";
          } else if ( myRoofSelection == "None" ) {
            myRoofSelection = "N";
          } else if ( myRoofSelection == "Galvanised" ) {
            myRoofSelection = "G";
          } else if ( myRoofSelection == "Painted" ) {
            myRoofSelection = "P";
          } else {
            myRoofSelection = "C";
          }
        }

        // This changes the formatting of the Infill selection...
        if ( myInfillSelection == "Yes" ) {
          myInfillSelection = "I";
        } else if ( (myInfillSelection == "No") || (myInfillSelection == "None" ) ) {
          myInfillSelection = "N";
        } else if ( myInfillSelection == "Solid Colour" ) {
          myInfillSelection = "S";
        } else if ( myInfillSelection == "Timber" ) {
          myInfillSelection = "T";
        } else {
          myInfillSelection = "N";
        }

        // This changes the formatting of the Fastener selection...
        if ( myFastenersSelection == "Galvanised" ) {
          myFastenersSelection = "G";
        } else if ( myFastenersSelection = "Stainless Steel") {
          myFastenersSelection = "G";
        } else {
          myFastenersSelection = "G";
        }

        // This changes the formatting of the Soffit selection...
        if ( mySoffitSelection == "Miniorb Soffit / No Sunscreen" ) {
          mySoffitSelection = "CN";
        } else if ( mySoffitSelection == "Timber Soffit / No Sunscreen" ) {
          mySoffitSelection = "TN";
        } else if ( mySoffitSelection == "Aluminium Soffit / No Sunscreen" ) {
          mySoffitSelection = "AN";
        } else if ( mySoffitSelection == "Miniorb Soffit / Miniorb Sunscreen" ) {
          mySoffitSelection = "CC";
        } else if ( mySoffitSelection == "Timber Soffit / Timber Sunscreen" ) {
          mySoffitSelection = "TT";
        } else if ( mySoffitSelection == "Aluminium Soffit / Aluminium Sunscreen" ) {
          mySoffitSelection = "AA";
        } else {
          mySoffitSelection = "CN";
        }

        // If a Lull family item is selected, the src attribute url is updated... "C" is a hard-coded placeholder for Footing choices (between Cast-In or Slab Fixed), hence the "C" - Cast-In.
        if ( productFamily[p] == "Lull" ) {

          // If all choices have been chosen...
          if ( mySizeSelection || myFrameSelection || myFastenersSelection ) {
            var url = "//placeholder.com.au/"+ productFamily[p] + "_" + productType[t] + "/" + productFamily[p].toUpperCase() + "_" + mySizeSelection + myFrameSelection + "C" + myFastenersSelection + ".jpg";
            $('.product-main-image img').attr("src",url);
            console.log(url);
          } else {
            console.log("All options must be chosen.");
          }

        // If a Leios family item is selected, the src attribute url is updated... "C" is a hard-coded placeholder for Footing choices (between Cast-In or Slab Fixed), hence the "C" - Cast-In.
        } else if ( productFamily[p] == "Leios" ) {

          // If all choices have been chosen...
          if ( mySizeSelection || myColumnSelection || myFrameSelection || myRoofSelection || myInfillSelection || myFastenersSelection ) {
            var url = "//placeholder.com.au/"+ productFamily[p] + "_" + productType[t] + "_V3/" + productFamily[p].toUpperCase() + "_" + mySizeSelection + myColumnSelection + myFrameSelection + myRoofSelection + myInfillSelection + "C" + myFastenersSelection + ".jpg";
            $('.product-main-image img').attr("src",url);
            console.log(url);
          } else {
            console.log("All options must be chosen.");
          }

        // If a Beaches family item is selected, the src attribute url is updated... "C" is a hard-coded placeholder for Footing choices (between Cast-In or Slab Fixed), hence the "C" - Cast-In.
        } else if ( productFamily[p] == "Beaches" ) {

          // If all choices have been chosen...
          if ( mySizeSelection || myFrameSelection || myRoofSelection || mySoffitSelection || myInfillSelection || myFastenersSelection ) {
            var url = "//placeholder.com.au/"+ productFamily[p] + "_" + productType[t] + "/" + productFamily[p].toUpperCase() + "_" + mySizeSelection + myFrameSelection + myRoofSelection + mySoffitSelection + myInfillSelection + "C" + myFastenersSelection + ".jpg";
            $('.product-main-image img').attr("src",url);
            console.log(url);
          } else {
            console.log("All options must be chosen.");
          }

        } else {
            console.log("No product family showing up...");
        }

        console.log("\n///////////////////////////////// END OF ON-CHANGE LOOP /////////////////////////////////\n\n");
    }); // End of On change function.
  } // End of sizeRange loop.
} // End of productType loop.
} // End of productFamily loop.
});
```

Comment: Safari doesn't yet support the EcmaScript 6 `let` keyword. See http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: Damn. Is there an alternative I can use to achieve the same effect?

Comment: You can use `var` to get function scope variables instead of block scope.

Comment: I tried using `for ( var p in productFamily )` and that ended up breaking the script - was that the correct way to use var in my case? I also tried initiating `p`, `t` and `i` outside of the loops, same effect.

Comment: Unless you have other variables `p`, `t`, or `i` within the same function, it should have worked.

Answer (score 0):

@Barmar hit the nail on the head - the type of for loop I was attempting was part of ES6 and not supported by all browsers, I ended up using the `forEach` function, [courtesy of this link](https://gist.github.com/kamilogorek/ab14da9f84de14452a62#file-foreach-js).

Here is a snippet of how I've used it in my script:

```
  productFamily.forEach(function (value, p) {
    productType.forEach(function (value, t) {
      sizeRange.forEach(function (value, i) {
```